# HTML Replace css background-image to video

Tags: html, css, image, video, web

I would like to replace and change my css background-image to video, does someone know how to make it ?
Any way to change the image to uploaded video src? Without breaking the split left and right.

The images was path under css. with .side-left {background-image: url('left.jpg');} i did try to change the source left.jpg to myvideo.mp4 but it seems doesnt work.

**my html**

```
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="splitlayout" class="splitlayout">
                <div class="intro">

                <header class="codropsheader clearfix">
                            <!--
                            <span>Rex Photography<span class="bp-icon bp-icon-about" data-content="Photography is the science, art, application and practice of creating durable images by recording light or other electromagnetic radiation, either electronically by means of an image sensor, or chemically ..."></span></span>
                            -->

                            <a href="index.html"><img class="headerlogo" src="logo2.jpg" title="PixPodium" alt="PixPodium"/></a>

                            <!--
                            <nav>

                                <a href="project.html" class="bp-icon bp-icon-prev" data-info="Go to Projects" ><span>Go to Commercials</span></a>
                                <a href="wedding.html" class="bp-icon bp-icon-next" data-info="Go to Weddings"><span>Go to Weddings</span></a>
                                <!--
                                <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=16693" class="bp-icon bp-icon-drop" data-info="back to the Codrops article"><span>back to the Codrops article</span></a>
                                -->
                                <!--
                                <a href="contact.html" class="bp-icon bp-icon-archive" data-info="Contact Us"><span>Contact Us</span></a>

                            <!--
                            </nav>
                            -->


                            <div class="demos">
                                <a href="project.html">Commercials</a>
                                <a href="wedding.html">Weddings</a>
                                <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                            </div>

                </header>   
                  <div class="topWrapper" style ="display:none;">
                        <div class="side side-left" >

                            <div class="intro-content">
                                <!--

                                <div class="profile"><img src="img/profile1.jpg" alt="profile1"></div>

                                -->

                                <a href="project.html"><h1 ><span></span><span>Commercials</span></h1></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="overlay"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "bottomWrapper" style = "display:none;">
                        <div class="side side-right" >
                            <div class="intro-content">
                                <!-- Original Code Start
                                <h1 style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);"><span >Weddings</span><span>Weddings</span></h1>
                                Original Code End -->

                                <a href="wedding.html"><h1><span></span><span>Weddings</span></h1></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="overlay"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /intro -->


            </div><!-- /splitlayout -->
        </div><!-- /container -->


    </body>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".topWrapper").fadeIn(1000);
            $(".bottomWrapper").fadeIn(1000);
            //$(".topWrapper").fadeIn("slow");
            //$("#div3").fadeIn(3000);

        });
        </script>
</html>
```

**my css**

```
    html, body, 
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /*
    background: #fff;
    */
    background: #fff;
}

.splitlayout {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Intro sides */
.side {
    position: fixed;
    /*top: 0; */
    z-index: 100;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.open-left .side,
.open-right .side {
    cursor: default;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 499;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.side-left .overlay {

    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

}

.side-right .overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.side-left {

    /* Original code Start
    left: 0;
    background: #47a3da;
    color: #fff;
    outline: 1px solid #47a3da; /* avoid gap 
    Original Code End */

    left: 0;
    float: left;
    background-image: url('left.jpg');
                         /* <------ */
    background-size: cover;                      /* <------ */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;              /* optional, center the image*/
    /*background: #47a3da;*/
    color: #fff;
    /*outline: 1px solid #47a3da; /* avoid gap */
}

.side-right {
    /* Original code Start
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    color: #47a3da;
    /*outline: 1px solid #fff; /* avoid gap */

    right: 0;
    background-image: url('right.jpg');
    background-size: cover;                      /* <------ */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;              /* optional, center the image*/

    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using video tag in html:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Any alternate text.
</video>
```

And in css:

```
#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp) will help you to learn and implement the feature that you need.

Comment: @KeznTeh Your Welcome :) Please accept it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Make the video a static or absolute div within the body.
Set it to width and height 100%.
Position the content over it.

See this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zrjqctov/7/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#videobackground {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#videobackground iFrame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="videobackground">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ztc6_elMg60" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div>
      <h1>
        Content here
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="demos">
      <a href="project.html">Commercials</a>
      <a href="wedding.html">Weddings</a>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```